# how to insert images inside a textarea and email them using php?

Tags: php, html, image, textarea

Peace all, I am working on a newsletter but i wonder, how i would be able to add images to the textarea that contains the body of the email and send the image with its details to the user through a `mail();` php function. how can i add an image inside the textarea? thanks in advance

here is the form:-

```
<form action="" method="post">
Subject<font color="red">*</font><br>
<input type="text" name="subject"><br><br>
body<font color="red">*</font><br>
<textarea name="body"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Email users">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be you need WYSIWYG .

Nice one http://www.tinymce.com/

Your url to image has to absolute like http://example.com/img/img.png not /img/img.png

Answer (score 1):

You can't display an image directly inside a textarea control.

The closes you can get is overlay an image on it, but it will not be part of the information in the textarea. That is, text will not flow around it and when posting the form it will not be included in the data for the textarea.

Perhaps a writable div (content editable) would suit your purposes better.

You can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/6bCRJ/

HTML

```
<div contentEditable="true"> type here
    <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCze-mfukcuvzKk7Ilj2zQ0CS6PbOkq7ZhRInnNd1Yz3TQzU4e&t=1" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: ok, but that means the website owner will need to know programming skills and this is not possible so is there a way for me to make a system that allows the website owner to send images to his customers directly without doing any programming?

Comment: I do not think so. You may help the website owner to do all this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option for WYSIWYG [**KendoUI Editor**](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also include this "data-mce-src" for image sent in mail

```
data-mce-src='".$base_url."/images/mail_footer.jpg'
```

Answer (score -1):

hey sure its late but i found this great plugin it allows changing the cursor, adding animated images, video links, images and and and 
http://youtu.be/Jf_FqbzJlrI there is a download link, its a pay plugin, but well worth the price, comes with thousands of icons and animated aicons saves tons of work